# WPF graphics card problem

Tags: wpf

I recently bought a new laptop - a Toshiba Satellite A660, which has an ATI mobility Radeon HD 5650.  To save power it disables the Radeon when on battery power and uses integrated graphics.

I have some WPF apps which have common controls like buttons and checkboxes mapped onto 3D surfaces which can be rotated and moved.   With the Radeon running sometimes when I press a button or check a box and it only **partially** repaints or a button will press in and not pop back out again.  It looks terrible!  If I switch to battery power **everything works fine**.

I feel totally stuck.  I suspect a driver problem or flaw in DirectX on the card but the Radeon's drivers are up to date.

Any suggestions for fixes?    Is WPF really that sensitive to the graphics card and driver on modern PC's?   How do developers test and deploy WPF apps to minimize things like this?

(one example - from a textbook -  is pure XAML, basically no code behind, so I put the XAML file on a server:  http://pnart.com/temp/WPF_XAML_Example.xaml  - it works fine on 4 computers plus the Toshiba when it's on battery)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, WPF depends on DirectX and therefore the graphics drivers. Try turning hardware acceleration off. If that fixes the problem, you know for sure it's a driver issue.

Comment: That's what I did - in the original post I said that when I switch to integrated graphics the problem vanishes.   But the ATI Mobility Radeon is major graphics card and its drivers are up to date and this is a brand new PC - if WPF can't be counted on to run on that how are we supposed to deploy WPF apps?   Even though these run on 4 other PC's is there something I could be doing to cause this?