# WPF strategies to avoid graphics card sensitivities?

Tags: wpf

This is essentially a re-state of a question I asked yesterday because the one answer I got didn't appear to understand my question so I must have been unclear.  My bad.

Because WPF relies on DirectX it's very sensitive to internals of cards and drivers. I have a case where some simple WPF programs render incorrectly on one modern, brand-new PC with a major brand high-performance graphics card and current drivers.   The problems go away if I disable the graphics card (so it uses the integrated grahics).   So I know it's the card or drivers.   These programs render fine on several other older PC's I've tried them on.

As WPF programmers are there deployment strategies or programming strategies we can use to minimize the risks and exposures to stuff like this?  If we can't count on WPF rendering properly on major brands of PC's and graphics cards what **can** we do?    How common are issues like this with WPF?

Original post:  [WPF graphics card problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729542/wpf-graphics-card-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are having hardware-dependent rendering issues, you can work around it by forcing software rendering. (In my experience, this has almost never been necessary; in most cases of video glitches, ensuring that customers have the latest drivers has solved the problem. As a WPF developer, I don't worry about this problem.)

If you're using WPF 4, use [RenderOptions.ProcessRenderMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.processrendermode.aspx) to force software rendering for the current process.

In WPF 3.5, your only option is to disable hardware rendering for all WPF applications on by editing the registry. Create/open the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics` key and create a DWORD value `DisableHWAcceleration` with the value 0x1.

For more details, see [Software Rendering Usage in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2010/06/22/software-rendering-usage-in-wpf.aspx).

Comment: Thank you - this is exactly the sort of information I'm looking for!  .... with regard to ensuring customers have current drivers, are most WPF apps written for target users where the developer has any input into that, e.g., in-house corporate user-bases?   I write scheduling sw for musicians - ordinary users with random ordinary PC's.   Is WPF a bad choice for that?

Comment: @Peter: The WPF application I primarily work on (Logos Bible Software) is mainly deployed to pastors and other "ordinary" users. They tend to run older systems that have integrated graphics or low-end DX10 cards (i.e., not gamer rigs). In our experience, the benefits of WPF (graphically rich, easy to develop & style UI, data binding, animations, etc.) far outweigh the cost of tech support occasionally needing to walk a non-tech-savvy user through a driver upgrade.

Comment: @Peter: WPF does have more compatibility issues (e.g., http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/11/how_to_crash_every_wpf_application.html) -- you will almost certainly have more users who just can't get your software to work at all by using WPF (over WinForms), but I think you'll make the majority of your users happier by being able to deliver a better UI with WPF.